# What is the store variable in the partition method (of the QuickSort algorithm) doing?

Tags: java, quicksort

I was looking at [this](https://github.com/Code2Bits/Algorithms-in-Java/blob/master/sort/src/main/java/com/code2bits/algorithm/sort/QuickSort.java) simple implementation of the QuickSort algorithm.

I'm having trouble with the partition method. I've re-named the variables to help me understand. I understand most of the method, but there's one variable whose purpose I don't get. That's the `store` variable.

Here's my version of this method:

```
private int partition(int[] array, int startIndex, int endIndex) 
{
        int pivotIndex = getPivot(startIndex, endIndex);
        swapElements(array, pivotIndex, endIndex);

        pivotIndex = endIndex;
        int store = startIndex;

        for(int currentIndex = startIndex; (currentIndex <= endIndex - 1); currentIndex++) 
        {
            if(array[currentIndex] <= array[pivotIndex]) 
            {
                swapElements(array, currentIndex, store);
                store++;
            }
        }

        swapElements(array, store, pivotIndex);
        pivotIndex = store;
        return pivotIndex;
}
```

What is the purpose of the `store` variable? If `startIndex` and `currentIndex` are already pointing to the first index of the array, why you need `store` to do the same thing? What is it doing?

Comment: This is incidental, but `(currentIndex <= endIndex - 1)` is cleaner as `currentIndex < endIndex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your simpler question, you should be able to see that `store` does not remain the same as `currentIndex` as the iteration progresses. It is only incremented if `array[currentIndex] <= array[pivotIndex]` is true for a particular iteration. - so `store` is generally going to be smaller than `currentIndex`.

To answer more specifically, what is going on is that you pick a `pivotIndex` at the beginning that is pointing at some value.  Then you are moving elements around in the table so that all of the values smaller than the `pivotIndex` value are before that value in the array, and all of the values greater than the `pivotIndex` value are after that value in the array. `store` is keeping track of where to move the next value that is found to be smaller than the `pivotIndex` value.  That value is moved to the `store` position, and then `store` is incremented to move past that value and represent where the next smaller value should be placed.

At the end of the iteration, `store` is by design pointing to where the pivot value should be, since all values before `store` are less than that value, and all values after `store` are greater.  So at the end, the pivot value is moved to the location pointed to by `store`, and `store` becomes the final index of the partitioning operation, the index pointing to the pivot value

Comment: Steve, I think you're right, but it's going to take me the rest of the day to wrap my head around this. I'll have to test it to confirm what you said. Thank you and you too, Daly John, for helping out.

Comment: This is where print statements can be your friend.  Work with simple inputs, like 8-10 items, and for each iteration print the array and the values of all of the index values.

Comment: I admit that there's one thing I'm not perfectly clear on.  When it does the swap, it moves a value back in the array to be able to move the one it just tested forward in the array.  I think the idea is that that value has already been processed and is guaranteed to be greater than the pivot point, so it doesn't really matter where it goes as long as its after the pivot point, which it will be because the pivot point is where it came from and it's always being moved higher

Comment: the thing to know (you probably already do) is that this isn't sorting the array.  it's only making sure that it can be cut into two pieces at the pivot, and all of the values in one piece are lower than the pivot and all the values in the other are higher.  As the pieces get smaller and smaller, the array becomes sorted.

Comment: The key is that it never has to shift all of the values to make room for a new value, because it always does a swap.  This is what makes it faster in the end over a brute force insertion sort.  In an insertion sort, values can be moved many times because you keep shifting all the values up or down one to make room for a new one.  I think the thing about a quicksort is that there are many fewer moves to get to a sorted array.